# If explicitly implement a getter, is the ivar still created?

Tags: ios, objective-c, properties

I am trying to understand all scenarios about properties, mostly when an ivar is automatically created and when it is not. Please tell me if I am correct in my following scenarios:

1. A property is implicitly readwrite. If a readwrite property is declared, and the getter and setter are **both** implemented explicitly, is it true that there will be no ivar automatically generated?
2. Say another readwrite property is declared, and this time only the getter is explicitly implemented. The ivar will be automatically generated because it will be automatically generated as long as one of the two (getter or setter) of the property is **not** explicitly implemented.
3. Basically the same as scenario 2, except this time it is the setter that is explicitly implemented. The ivar will be automatically generated because it will be automatically generated as long as one of the two (getter or setter) of the property is **not** explicitly implemented.

And just to clarify, when the ivar is created, will it **always** have a preceding underscore "_"?

Answer (score 1):

All your statements are correct (assuming that you don't explicitly provide a @synthesize statement).

Reference: ["Encapsulating Data"](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/EncapsulatingData/EncapsulatingData.html) in the "Programming with Objective-C" documentation:

> **Note:** The compiler will automatically synthesize an instance variable
>   in all situations where it’s also synthesizing at least one accessor
>   method. If you implement both a getter and a setter for a `readwrite`
>   property, or a getter for a `readonly` property, the compiler will
>   assume that you are taking control over the property implementation
>   and won’t synthesize an instance variable automatically.
>
> If you still
>   need an instance variable, you’ll need to request that one be
>   synthesized:
>
> ```
> @synthesize property = _property;
> ```

Comment: If everything is done automatically, what is the point of ever doing "@"synthesize explicitly? Like for "@"synthesize property = _property   if that line was left out, it would happen anyway?

Comment: @user3451821: Only if you provide both setter and getter *and* need the ivar. (You could declare the ivar directly in the `@implementation` or in a class extension. Using `@synthesize` emphasises that it is related to a property.) - And there may be cases where you want the ivar to have a different name.

Comment: @user3451821: Does this answer your question or do you need more information?